# excel vba、開いたブック内の作業グループを自動解除したい

Tags: vba, excel

■課題
excelブックを開くタイミングで、作業グループを自動解除する方法を探してます。
対象は１つのブックだけではなく、とある数台のPCで開くブックを全て対象にしたいと考えます。
(環境＝win7+Excel2010、Win10+excel2016、2つ利用）

■理由
作業グループに気づかずに編集すると、意図しない変更が発生し、これを回避したいと考えます。

■当方の試行錯誤
個人用マクロブック（PERSONAL.XLSB）に次のようなマクロを入れてみました。

```
Sub auto_open()
    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "作業グループを解除します"
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets(1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

単なるブック（Book1.xlsmなど）にマクロを入れると、動作したのですが、
個人用マクロブック（PERSONAL.XLSB）にマクロを入れると、エラーになりました。
typename(ActiveWindow)="Nothing"となっていることが原因だと考えます。

少し直せば、解決するでしょうか？　別の方法で解決するでしょうか？

以上、
本課題の解決方法ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授よろしくお願いします。

---

**コメントより追記**

- エラーは以下です。
  「実行時エラー'91':オブジェクト変数またはWithブロック変数が設定されていません。」
- エラーを確認した環境は、win7+excel2010でした。
- `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Select`も上と同じエラーでした。
- `typename(ActiveWorkbook)`も"Nothing"でした。
  `ActiveWindow`も`ActiveWorkbook`も"Nothing"という状況なので、
  個人用マクロブック（PERSONAL.XLSB）のauto_openのタイミングでは、
  `ActiveWindow`も`ActiveWorkbook`も定まっていない様子です

Comment: エラーの番号と内容も記載できますか？また、実行してエラーが出たのはExcel2010と2016どちらでしょうか？どちらもですか？`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Select`ではどうでしょう？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
●エラーは以下です。「実行時エラー'91':オブジェクト変数またはWithブロック変数が設定されていません。」
●エラーを確認した環境は、win7+excel2010でした。
●ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Selectも上と同じエラーでした。
・・・
typename(ActiveWorkbook)も"Nothing"でした。ActiveWindowもActiveWorkbookも"Nothing"という状況なので、個人用マクロブック（PERSONAL.XLSB）のauto_openのタイミングでは、ActiveWindowもActiveWorkbookも定まっていない様子です。
・・・
作業グループ解除したい場合、上の試行錯誤は、外していたのかも知れません。

Comment: 本件とほぼ同じ課題を、6年前に試された方のブログが見つかりました。
http://yamav102.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2013/03/post-126f.html
なかなか大変そうな印象です。